# Type '{}' is missing the following properties - Angular 9.1.1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, forms

I'm using a Angular CLI : 9.1.1 so I try to update some of data not all of them,

```
form: UserInfo = {adresse : {}};
```

**UserInfo.interface**

```
export interface UserInfo {
    id_user: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    nom: string;
    prenom: string;
    telephone: number;
    password: string;
    specialite: string;
    adresse?: Address;
   
}
```

this error has been applied :

```
 Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Address': id_adresse, adresse, code_postal, ville, and 2 more.ts(2740)
    user-info.ts(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'adresse' which is declared here on type 'UserInfo'
```

That's working but when I restart my app the project does'nt start. Can someone help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: But the properties are missing. Change your type definitions to make them optional

Comment: How can I make them optional

Comment: Use '?' operator after the property name like `id?: number`, this will make it optional on the class/interface if you prefer this approach.

Comment: Still the same error applied

Comment: Show the UserInfo definition here. (Editing your question)

Comment: as what @EliasSoares said, change the type definition inside 'Address' to be optional, `id_address?: number`, `adresse?: string;`, etc. Or, you could declare the values manually. `form: UserInfo = { adresse: { id_adresse: 1, adresse: "some address", ... } }`.

Comment: @EliasSoares I upated my quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the properties optional by using `?` operator which denotes the compiler not to expect values while instantiating.

```
export interface UserInfo {
    id_user?: string;
    username?: string;
    email?: string;
    nom?: string;
    prenom?: string;
    telephone?: number;
    password?: string;
    specialists?: string;
    adresse?: Address;
   
}
```